# Python 32 'win32ui' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bot made to run super hexagon (just for fun) at http://pastebin.com/X34Qxrxx

Unfortunately, whenever I run it with IDLE 3.5 32 bit, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 223, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 213, in main
window_handle = win32ui.FindWindow(None, u"Super Hexagon").GetSafeHwnd()
NameError: name 'win32ui' is not defined
```

Can anyone help? I'm not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, it is `win32gui`. Just check.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should do to check

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
window_handle = win32ui.FindWindow(None, u"Super Hexagon").GetSafeHwnd()
```

try :

```
window_handle = win32ui.win32ui.FindWindow(None, u"Super Hexagon").GetSafeHwnd()
```

or

```
window_handle = FindWindow(None, u"Super Hexagon").GetSafeHwnd()
```

does this works ?

Comment: Now it says (NameError: name 'FindWindow' is not defined)